# How to insert dynamic text box values of multiple rows from windows form into the db.(Using C#, Linq-to-SQL classes, SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create a form with some dynamic text boxes when we click on a add  button and if we click on the save button those text boxes along with its properties should be saved to database and it was done but, for a single row only. Now I want to insert all the multiple dynamic rows with single insert button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal TextBox tb1;
    internal TextBox tb2;
    internal TextBox tb3;
    internal TextBox tb4;
    internal ComboBox cm;

    int lbltext = 1;
    int A = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show();

        if (A > 12)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert More than 12 records in a page");
        }

        A += 1;
        lbltext += 1;
    }

    internal new void Show()
    {
        i++;

        tb1 = new TextBox()
        {
            Text = (lbltext).ToString() + ".",
            Height = 22,
            Width = 17,
            Left = 9,
            Top = 140 + A * 36,
            // Parent = FormWindowState.Normal,
            Name = "textbox" + i
        };

        i++;

        tb2 = new TextBox
        {
            Height = 22,
            Width = 60,
            Left = 43,
            Top = 140 + A * 36,
            Name = "textbox" + i
        };

        i++;

        tb3 = new TextBox
        {
            Height = 22,
            Width = 64,
            Left = 122,
            Top = 140 + A * 36,
            Name = "textbox" + i
        };

        i++;

        tb4 = new TextBox
        {
            Height = 22,
            Width = 80,
            Left = 220,
            Top = 140 + A * 36,
            Name = "textbox" + i
        };

        j++;

        cm = new ComboBox();
        cm.Text = "-NONE-";
        cm.Items.Add("-PRESENT-");
        cm.Items.Add("-LEAVE-");
        cm.Items.Add("-HOLIDAY-");
        cm.Left = 358;
        cm.Width = 92;
        cm.Height = 22;
        cm.Name = "ComBoBox" + j;
        cm.Top = 140 + A * 36;

        this.Controls.Add(tb1);
        this.Controls.Add(tb2);
        this.Controls.Add(tb3);
        this.Controls.Add(tb4);
        this.Controls.Add(cm);
    }

    internal void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox3 tb = new TextBox3();
        TextBox4 dtb4 = new TextBox4();
        TextBox5 dtb5 = new TextBox5();
        TextBox6 dtb6 = new TextBox6();

        ComboBox2 dcm = new ComboBox2();

        Label lb = new Label();

        ExampleDataContext dc = new ExampleDataContext();

        try
        { 
             lb.textvalue= lbltext.ToString();
             // For storing S.No
             tb.textvalue = lbltext - 1;
             tb.HeightValue = tb1.Height;
             tb.WidthValue = tb1.Width;
             tb.LeftValue = tb1.Left;
             tb.TopValue = tb1.Top;
             tb.name = tb1.Name;
             // select tb.textvalue;

             dc.TextBox3s.InsertOnSubmit(tb);
             dc.SubmitChanges();

             //For storing Id
             dtb4.textvalue = tb2.Text;
             dtb4.HeightValue = tb2.Height;
             dtb4.WidthValue = tb2.Width;
             dtb4.LeftValue = tb2.Left;
             dtb4.TopValue = tb2.Top;
             dtb4.name = tb2.Name;
             dc.TextBox4s.InsertOnSubmit(dtb4);
             dc.SubmitChanges();

             //For storing Name
             dtb5.textvalue = tb3.Text;
             dtb5.HeightValue = tb3.Height;
             dtb5.WidthValue = tb3.Width;
             dtb5.LeftValue = tb3.Left;
             dtb5.TopValue = tb3.Top;
             dtb5.name = tb3.Name;
             dc.TextBox5s.InsertOnSubmit(dtb5);
             dc.SubmitChanges();

             //For storing Designation
             dtb6.textvalue = tb4.Text;
             dtb6.HeightValue = tb4.Height;
             dtb6.WidthValue = tb4.Width;
             dtb6.LeftValue = tb4.Left;
             dtb6.TopValue = tb4.Top;
             dtb6.name = tb4.Name;
             dc.TextBox6s.InsertOnSubmit(dtb6);
             dc.SubmitChanges();

             //For storing Attendence ComboBox
             dcm.LeftValue = cm.Left;
             dcm.HeightValue = cm.Height;
             dcm.TopValue = cm.Top;
             dcm.WidthValue = cm.Width;
             dcm.textvalue = cm.Text;
             dcm.name = cm.Name;
             dc.ComboBox2s.InsertOnSubmit(dcm);
             dc.SubmitChanges();

             MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record already exists" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        this.WindowState = Properties.Settings.Default.F1State;
    }
}
```